# Drawing text in Cinder

Tags: cinder

I was wondering if there is a way to draw a `gl::texture` file with out having to use the `gl::draw` command every loop. Is there a way I can draw it once, and then not worry about it.

Drawing the image on every loop of `draw()` is slowing down my application, so I'd like to only draw things once on the screen and then update them if need be.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from Cinder's tutorials:

"When you create a new Cinder project, you will notice there are a few functions declared for you. Every Cinder project is made up of three main functions. You initialize your variables in the setup() method which is called once when your program begins. You make changes to those variables in the update() method. And finally, you draw() content in your program window. Update and draw are the heartbeat of any Cinder project.  UpdateSetup, then update and draw, update and draw, update and draw, on and on until you quit the application."

There's a way though to draw objects permanently in OpenGL and concequently in Cinder but I wouldn't recommend it. Is to disable gl::clear() in your draw function. You can't though selectively delete any unneeded object. You will have to render your scene from scratch. Think of OpenGL's frame-buffer more of a canvas. Everytime you call gl::clear() you take the brush and you paint your canvas black or what ever color you specify with gl::clear(). After that the frame-buffer is "tabula rasa" you have to draw everything you want to display from scratch. If you don't state any gl::clear() command when you draw a new object is like your canvas stays intact and you draw your object on top of the already drawn.